# SSL Socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, client-server

How can I create a SSL Socket connection?

I realy need to create a keystore? This keystore should be shared with all my client applications?

I have create a server with the following code:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory
                    .getDefault();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory
                    .createServerSocket(ServerProperties.getInstance()
                            .getVSSPAuthenticationPort());
```

I have create a client on android with the following code:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory
                .getDefault();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(
                host, authPort);

sslsocket.startHandshake();

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                sslsocket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                sslsocket.getInputStream()));
```

But when I try to connect, the following error is throwed:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:266)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:894)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:622)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:167)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need a certificate to establish an ssl connection, you can load the certificate inside a keystore or you can load the certificate itself. I will show some examples for the keystore option.

Your code needs some parameters to run :

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keyStoreFile -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystorePassword Server
```

You can also load the keystore with java code , the simplest solution for this is to set the system properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", 'keystoreFile');
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", 'keystorePassword ');
```

Also you can load the keystore with a different way, its more complicated but you have the ability to  do more complex things :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystoreFile"), "keystorePassword".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(ks, "keystorePassword".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509"); 
tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers(); 
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null); 

SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory(); 
SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(serverport);
SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
```

For the clients there are a few changes in the code last lines, the 3 last lines will be replaced with these :

```
SSLSocketFactory ssf = sc.getSocketFactory(); 
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(serverip, serverport);
s.startHandshake();
```

If you want to load a keystore for android the type will have to be  "BKS" and not "JKS". You can find easily resources for creating a keystore.

Comment: You only need a certificate to establish an SSL connection if the server you are connecting to require it. Ditto a keystore.

Comment: Are you saying that the certificate is optional ?

Comment: I said you only need it if the server requires it. I wouldn't describe that as 'optional': more configuration-dependent.

Comment: You are talking about the user certificate and of course your are right! I am not on the other hand, this was my misunderstanding ;)

Comment: There is no evidence here that the server doesn't have a certificate.

Comment: @VGe0rge why do you have TrustManager on the server side? Shouldn't this be on client side?

Comment: I followed https://gpotter2.github.io/tutos/en/sslsockets : there's some help on how to build the certificates then a few util classes. It also explains how to make it work on Android