# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on a tomcat server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ssl, https

I want to get the content of a url with the **https** protocol. The problem is that when this code is executed from a **tomcat server**, I get a **HandshakeException**.

```
url = new URL("https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Txt/Nivo/nivo.20140309.csv");    
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
```

I tried to look into other stackoverflow questions ([How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection) or [SSL Socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787419/ssl-socket-connection)) and it seems I need to define a `KeyStore`.

I have no idea of how to do this.

The full error in the tomcat server is

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

What is the best way to acheve this?

Comment: That certificate is not self signed.  It's signed by Entrust.  You can import the Entrust CA into your existing java keystore.  Google java keytool, or type "keytool -importcert -help" on the command line.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried to create a keystore `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA` but it keeps looping in the console asking for my name, city, country, etc. Is it always that hard to acces a https url with tomcat?

Comment: Java ships with a keystore, you can just use that.  you don't need to make a new one.  And you shouldn't be generating any keys.  You have to download the Entrust certificate and import it.

Comment: Okay. I think you can forget about importing the CA cert.  I just checked and it's already in the java ca root store.  You're probably battling with tomcat overriding the default keystore.

Comment: Does your application override its default truststore or trustmanager anywhere? Perhaps in the catalina.sh (or .bat) with `-Djavax.net.trustStore=...` or somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

The default java truststore ($JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts) contains the CA cert for donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr.  Most likely tomcat is using a different one.

You should be able to force it by updating the tomcat startup script to include the castore location.  Something like this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```